# How to clear output in Vte.Terminal?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, vte

How to clear all output in Vte.Terminal ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What about printing an amount of line equivalent to the screen size?

Answer (score 1):

use the os library

```
import os

os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would only clear the text *visible* in the terminal, but, you can run the `cls` command or tinker with the `feed()` method and empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having some problems of my own with Vte so I don't know if I'm the right person to answer.

Have you tried replacing the old terminal with another in the container? It's not clearing, but there will be an empty terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
vte.feed('\033[2J')
```

For other escape sequences:

- [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)
- [ANSI escape code (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
vte.fork_command("clear")
```